# Insert timer function in router backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need insert in my router a function that works every specified time(example 5 secs), but the problem is that the counter restart count everytime I comeback to the home.
If i open my application the counter starts and even if i go to another page it count correctly,but if i return to home the counter is restart.I've tried with bind and unbind but doesn't work.

This is my router:

```
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "user/:id":"userDetails",
        "settings":"settings",
        "friends":"friends",
        "mailbox":"mailbox",
        "landscape":"landscape"

    },

   initialize:function(){

   $(window).bind('onload', setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},5000));<---------
   $(window).unbind('onload');   <---------
   },


    home: function() {


 if (Parse.User.current()){

       var user=new Person();
       user.savePosition();

       new BarraScreamView();
       new MenuView();


    }

    else 

     new LoginView();

    },


 userDetails: function (id) {
     console.log(id);
     console.log(Models.utenti.get(id));
     var page=new UserDetailView({model:Models.utenti.get(id)});
     this.changePage(page);
  },
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it there ? Can't you do it out of the router scope ?

Comment: How are you creating your router? ``Router.initialize`` should only be called when the router first initialized (which is typically only once per "session" if you are doing a single page app). If you put a ``console.log`` within initialize, do you see multiple logs when switching between routes?

Comment: I've insert console.log into initialize and it logs only when i go to page home.

Comment: So it bind the function every time go home and restart the function timer...how can i resolve?Isn't strange that initialize is called on home page?

Comment: Is your browser reloading when you navigate to home? Initialize should only be called on the first page load. You should be able to switch back and forth between home and your routes without initializing the router.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the fragment identifier in an url (www.example.com/**#fragment**) does not cause the page to be reloaded. On the other hand, if you *remove* the fragment identifier, the page gets reloaded.

I assume that when you say *"every time I come back home"*, you mean everytime the url is modified so there is no fragment, the problem occurs.

If you add a new route #home, and visit `example.com/#home` instead of just `example.com/`, the problem should be fixed.

```
routes: {
    "": "home",
    "home": "home",
    ...
}
```

(**Edit**: you can also just use `example.com/#` as the home route without changing the routes-object)

**P.S.**

As Router.initialize() should only get called once, this code should suffice for the init:

```
initialize:function(){
  setInterval( function(){ alert("Hello") }, 5000 );
}
```